# Swift decode json with key starting as a number

Tags: json, swift

I have a json in following format:

```
let json = """
{
    "stuff": {
        "1": "one",
        "2": "two",
        "4": "four"
    }
}
```

question is how can i make my

```
struct Stuff: Codable, Equatable {
    let 1: String
    let 2: String
    let 4: String
}
```

compile and work?

i use to call this with below, and it works fine for everything but if let name starts with number it obviously won't compile

```
let obj = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. A variable must not start with a numeric character. Unalterable rule.

But you can map the names with `CodingKeys`

```
struct Stuff: Codable, Equatable {
    let one, two, four: String

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case one = "1",  two = "2", four = "4"}
}
```

Comment: a variable name can start also with underscore (nitpicking)

Comment: @Sulthan I specified the *rule* 

Answer (score 0):

You can't. [RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-6) standard for JSON dictates that the object key must be a string.

```
object = begin-object [ member *( value-separator member ) ]
           end-object

member = string name-separator value
```

Comment: yeah, i get that. but I'm not in the position to change external API :D